# /anaconda3/bin/python: No module named pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I tried to run 'python -m pip install "package"' command but it gives me this error:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named pip
```

I have python2 and python3 installed. Looks like that's messing up everything. 
And why it is using python in anaconda rather than the default one in /usr/bin/python?

Comment: What happened when you write `which pip`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip

Answer (score 3):

Actually, pip should be installed by default. In case something special happens, try to download get-pip.py
Then run the following (which may require administrator access):
python get-pip.py in terminal
(To have administrator access rights, simply type sudo su in terminal, and enter your password)

Please reference:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597906/how-to-install-pip-and-a-python-package-for-self-installed-python